# Developer Story - Is there a way to find out how many points are needed to reach "TOP 1%"?

Tags: discussion, developer-story

Yes, I know Stack Overflow is much more than simply "chasing stats". But I am curious. Is there a way to find out how many points I would need to reach the top 1% for any given tag?

My reason for asking:

If I am **50 points** away, I might spend the next couple of evenings writing and posting high quality answers on Stack Overflow.

If I am **500 points** away, I might not.

Comment: How's about we just assume that you're 50 points away so you can post some more high quality content?

Comment: You could make a SEDE query to do this.

Comment: @TravisJ - Is it documented anywhere how it is calculated? My developer story puts me in top 10% for `.net`. There are 107,684 answerers for questions with that tag and my score is ranked 2,687 amongst those. So I assume it must exclude some answerers from consideration as otherwise I would be top 5%. SEDE query https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/732352/top-x-percent#resultSets